# Guidance on storing and accessing objects/collections in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, caching

I'm currently working on an ASP.NET reporting application (C#) with an Oracle database (using EntitySpaces ORM). Performance/responsiveness is critical to the success of this application as it will be used by 1000's of people over the period of a few days. I desperately want to avoid round trips to the database as I know that this will be a bottleneck. My first thought (since the physical size of the database is relatively small) was to simply cache all of the database objects in the application cache and query them from cache as needed. I soon realized the flaw in my logic when ASP.NET started dropping items from the cache - presumably because too much memory was being used.

Is there another/better way to do this? Is there another method of storing a static collection when the application starts that I can guarantee won't be consumed by garbage collection? I'm well aware of page level caching but that won't help much since I'm essentially building a series of ad hoc reports that are unique to each individual user.

**EDIT:** Just to clarify a bit further, the size of all the data being cached is < 5 MB. The idea was to cache all of the objects and then just filter collections with linq.

Comment: Are you doing any paging of data? Allowing people to place filters? how many rows are we talking? There are trade offs no matter what method you choose. Some choices give you performance at the cost of memory, others give you performance at the cost of disk space. Keep in mind that depending on your App Pool settings (recycle after X time or X memory or X CPU), your entire App Pool may recycle dropping ALL of your cached items making application memory caching useless.

Comment: You could use some external caching server like NOSQL dbs. It is fairly easy to implement and it doesnt demand too much change of code. Lot of them are free and open source. If you are interested in these options let me know , I can point you to couple of sites.

Comment: I clarified the issue a little bit more above. The latest idea is to keep using application cache, but use the CacheItemPriority.NotRemovable option.

Answer (score 0):

As I am already sure you know, indexing is a good idea. After that, the hardware of your server will greatly impact the ability of the database to serve up data -> if you truly need some serious performance, switch to RAIDed SSDs, with nightly backups to regular HDs.

Beyond that, the design of your tables can impact its speed. Since you noted that the database is rather small (that needs to be qualified, as Oracle is usually used for the bigger stuff), there probably isn't much to do there.

You may want to use a multi-homed NIC, with a direct connection to the servers requesting the data, if you really need speed.

See, keeping stuff in memory isn't a really great idea, with regards to RDBMS, as it favors committing data to the disk over performance. If you don't mind the idea of data possibly going missing (not doing anything truly important / in need of backups), you could go with a memory-only database. And any database machine you build should be packed to the gills with processors and memory (no scrimping).

As a general rule, more performance can be had with tighter / more manual coding and exotic hardware, but the question will be, is it worth the price? The resources needed to get an extra 10% performance are akin to the resources needed for the additional precision of a Porsche piston versus a VW piston -> it will cost a factor of ten, over the previous amount to get that performance. The only people I know (off the top of my head) who have that kind of money, and need that kind of performance, work for either the cryptography wing of national governments, or high frequency trading firms.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the size of the data you need to store you can store it in the Application State:

How to: Save Values in Application State http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/94xkskdf.aspx

How to: Read Values from Application State http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y8hhek39.aspx

Finally, you can set the variable in the Application_Start method in the global.asax file of your application: http://www.techrepublic.com/article/working-with-the-aspnet-globalasax-file/5771721

Comment: Think carefully when using Application Start to look up and store data. Keep in mind that your application will hang on the first request while you perform all of these look ups before serving up the first request. This can add seconds on to your app starting a fresh app pool. A better approach would likely be to add items to the cache as needed perhaps or use the HTTP Cache and enable expiration so you can keep items in memory and if they haven't been used after X minutes, expire them (sliding expiration).